# Python2 datetime - Convert epoch time to UTC timestamp with offset

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.x, utc

I am using Python 2 due to reasons beyond my control and hence cannot upgrade to Python 3 (which has better support for timezones).

I have an epoch time like `1492464960.53` and I want to convert it into a timestamp like this `2017-04-17T21:36:00.530000+00:00`.

I tried using the following code but this does not give the `+00:00` part of the timestamp that I also need.

```
import datetime
created=1492464960.53
time_str = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(created).isoformat()
print(time_str)
>> 2017-04-17T21:36:00.530000
```

How can I add the `+00:00` part?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this out and it worked for me.

First to explain why original solution didn't work, from what I understand, the reason isoformat() will not work for above epoch value is because this method requires the object to return something with the 'utcoffset' attribute, however above float/epoch value returns 'None' when I tested it out with this attribute. 
The isoformat method may very well work if we weren't dealing with converting a float perhaps.

Anyways, onto the solution:

```
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo
import pytz
created = 1492464960.53
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(created)

##print results for above 'dt' variable

2017-04-17 21:36:00.530000

dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

##print results for above 'dt' variable

2017-04-17 21:36:00.530000+00:00

dt.isoformat()

##print results for above 'dt' variable

'2017-04-17T21:36:00.530000+00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can get the same result without using the pytz? I do not really have an option of installing it on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not sure what you mean exactly about installing pytz, I just pip installed pytz then added the import statement in my python shell on my local machine.

Not sure this is the best solution, however it seems to have worked so here is the alternative I can offer:

```
created = 1492464960.53
dt = dt.utcnow().fromtimestamp(created, dt.tzname()).isoformat()
```

**should print**

'2017-04-17T14:36:00.530000'

```
from datetime import time
t = time(00, 00, 00, tzinfo=dt.tzname())
tmstmp = dt.isoformat()+'+'+t.strftime("%M:%S %z")
```

**should print**

2017-04-17T21:36:00.530000+00:00

Comment: Please edit your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43461380) instead of posting another one.

Comment: My apologies Gerry, think this is the first or second question I've answered on Stackoverflow. Will make sure to edit in the future :)